# What is the purpose of the words 'over' and 'up' in expressions like 'go over/up to [some place]'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> I crossed **over to** the other side of the road.

Why not just 'crossed to'?

> Jane drove **up to** the driveway and honked to indicate her arrival.

So? Why not just 'drove to'?

Other than what are those for, I'm curious whether you can abstain from using them at all in such cases — from the standpoint of grammar, I mean. I guess, putting them ahead of 'to' like that would sound more natural and native-like, but let's talk grammar.

Comment: Your first example seems unnatural. What is it intended to mean- crossing from one sidewalk/pavement to the other on foot, or driving from the correct side of the road to the incorrect side of the road?

Comment: @JavaLatte No - Sergey's right. And it can be either on foot or driving. I'm trying to think WHY we say it!

Comment: @JavaLatte Say, on foot. But I don't think it matters

Comment: Yes, you could say either "crossed over the road" or "crossed to the other side". "Crossed _over_ to the other side" is perhaps a bit redundant, but all are grammatically correct/idiomatic.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev on foot, I would use 'over' if I used some sort of footbridge. I would not use 'over' if I simply walked on the road surface itself to the other side.

Comment: 'He's over in the kitchen area, wearing nothing but his hat and a baggy pair of Y-fronts'. Why? I don't understand. (the example is from Lexico, sense 1.1 of the adverb: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/over)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**drive to** means to proceed my car to a specified **place / destination**, but does not specify what happened when you got there.

> I drove to Berlin yesterday
>   I usually drive to the supermarket

**drive up to** means to move the car close to a specified **object**, but stops short of it- for example, approaching the service counter of a drive-thru McDonalds.

> I drove up to the counter

It can also mean driving to a place that is considered higher. This can be actually higher, for example mountains, or conceptually higher, for example northward or more important.

> I drive up to Chamonix (high up in the Alps)
>   I drove up to Scotland (north from England)
>   I drove up to London (more important)

Compare that with **drive onto**, which means moving a car so that it passes over or remains on top of the specified object.

> My neighbour drove onto my lawn whilst parking his car (passes over)
>   I drove the car onto the driveway. (remains on)

looking at your example sentence:

> Jane drove up to the driveway and honked to indicate her arrival.

This would mean that Jane moved the car so that it was close to the driveway- for example parked across the entrance to the driveway.

> Jane drove to the driveway and honked to indicate her arrival.

This would mean that Jane used a car to travel to the driveway, but does not indicate where exactly the car was located after she arrived.

Note that this is sentence is not idiomatic because, as I mentioned earlier, you **drive to** a place/destination, for example a city, country, street, somebody's house, tourist destination, supermarket, cinema, etc. A driveway is not perceived as a place/destination, but as an object- a part of your house. It would be better to say

> Jane drove to my house and honked to indicate her arrival

This also indicates that Jane travelled by car to my house but does not indicated where exactly the car was located after she arrived. She could have pulled onto the driveway, stopped next to the driveway or parked half way down the street.

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not specify what she did'? She honked

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I said "does not specify what she did with the car". Honking does not indicate where exactly she positioned the car.

Comment: You mean that 'to' can mean both that she was "on the driveway" or "close to the driveway", whereas 'up to' only means the latter, do I understand correctly?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I have updated my answer.